# Epoch to Date Not Working Properly

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, epoch

I am trying to do a simple epoch to date conversion using *SimpleDateFormat*. Whenever I run the program, I keep receiving invalid dates post-conversion. I have run the epoch stamps in a converter [and I also have the dates stored in an outside server], so I know what the output should be, but I am still receiving bad conversions. I have tried multiple mathematical changes to the *long* epochTime in experimenting, but to no avail. I do know [or at least am mostly sure] that my epoch timestamp is stored in milliseconds, thus requiring a * 1000 change. Here is what I have:

```
String convertedTime = null;

//(1) //startTime = startTime/1000;  --none of these three manipulations solve the issue
//(2) //startTime = startTime * 1000;
//(3) //long change = (long) startTime * 1000;

Date d = newDate(startTime); //startTime is *long* parameter passed into method

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm-dd-yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss");
convertedTime= formatter.format(d);
```

For example, if the epoch stamp is **1404327407738** and I do not include (1), (2), (3) I receive **56-02-2014 at 01:56:47 PM**

- Including (1) - 05-17-1970 at 12:05:27 AM
- Including (2) - 35-13-46471 at 05:35:38 AM
- Including (3) - 35-13-46471 at 05:35:38 AM (yes, I replaced change for startTime here)

I *should* receive 07-02-2014 at 01:56:47 PM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format string should be "MM-dd-yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss".

"MM" is for the month in year, "mm" is for the minutes in hour (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 1):

It should be MM:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss");
```